# input time value when step is 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My prob is when I choose 00:05:00 for instance, the seconds part is not displayed, only 00:05 is displayed

```js
$('#compute').click(function(){
alert($('#inputTime').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inputTime" type="time" step="1" value="00:00:00">
<br>
<input type="button" id="compute" value="compute">
```

Comment: This is down to how the browser reads the value, not JS/jQuery. If you need to show the value in a specific format you'll need to do it manually

Comment: but if you set it to the value 00:05:00 on the source code , the value shown is still 00:05:00.

Comment: If the last part is not displaying, you can assume that the last part is `:00`, isn't?

Comment: yes, that's what i will do in case there is not another better option